# How to send an email to a specific audience inside a journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, send-email

I need to create a journey builder where a salesforce data (quote lookup contact) inject the JB when entry criterias are satisfied and then an email is to be send to a fixed specific audience (5 emails) instead of sending the email to the contact which is in the quote lookup.
What is the best way to do that?
Thank you

Comment: The email needs to be sent in near real-time?

Comment: Yes, you were thinking about using automation?

Comment: But there is a latency of 1h

Comment: @Macca, what would you use if there is no such temporal constraint?

Comment: If you need these emails to go out immediately, there are a few possibilities. If you're sending an email to the customer, you could use some AMPScript in your email that calls a CloudPage to start a triggered send. You could potentially use an API Triggered Send from an Apex code. You could create a Custom JB activity to send to your list. I'm sure there are other potential solutions. An Automation would be simplest, but like you say, you'd only be able to fire the automation once per hour (or more frequently if you have duplicate Automations running a 0, 15, 30 and 45 minutes past the hour).